# In shiny app, how to illustrate an example to change reactive and a dependent reactiveValues with only one click event?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Here's my app displaying a greeting with names and showing the number of letters of the name.

I would like to change the `name` and `rv$len` on one single click, but I need to click twice to get the `rv$len` changed to 4. Is there anything I can do to first update the `name` to `pikapika`, then manually change `rv$len` to `4` with a single click?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Thanks in advance for your help"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("name", "name of the user", value = "TEST"),
            actionButton(inputId = "Example", label = "pikapika as an example"),
        ),
        mainPanel(
           verbatimTextOutput("greetings")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    name <- reactive(input$name)
    rv <- reactiveValues(len = 4)
    # by default it reads the number of characters
    observe({
        rv$len <- nchar(name())
    })
    greeting <- reactive(paste("Hello", name(), "! Your name has", rv$len, "letters."))
    
    output$greetings <- renderPrint(greeting())
    # I would like to illustrate with a custom case
    observeEvent(input$Example, {
        updateTextInput(inputId = "name", value = "pikapika")
        rv$len <- 4
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Thanks from Pikachu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU26l.png)

Comment: Commenting out `updateTextInput()` might do it.  Why do you need `updateTextInput()`?

Comment: Thanks for @YBS 's comment. I would like to clarify what is needed: 1) change the `name` to 'pikapika' and 2) change the `rv$len` to 4, So that it shows `[1] "Hello pikapika ! Your name has 4 letters."` after a single click (now it needs 2 clicks).